# How to get multiple matches from single RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

i am currently using Javascript and am trying to deal with some regex. What i want to do is, have a string that is something like this:

```
this is a test [type:string] further test [type:string]
```

What i want to do, is be able to use regex to get the text in between each set of brackets. Ultimately i want to end up with these 2 values separately, or together in a list (Able to tell them apart even if they are the same)

So i would want to get out

[type:string]
[type:string]

twice.

I know i can do this using:

```
\[(.*?)\]
```

but when i do, it only matches the first bracket set, i want it to match all of them, and i can't seem to find a way to do that. Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `g` modifier (global match):

```js
var string = 'this is a test [type:string1] further test [type:string2]';

var matches = string.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);

console.log(matches);
```

Comment: This ended up doing it for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can extract each value individually:

```
var str = "this is a test [type:number] further test [type:string]";
var reg = /\[([a-z]+):([a-z]+)\]/g;
while (match = reg.exec(str)) {
   console.log("type=" + match[1], " and value=" + match[2]);
}
```

Will log:

```
type=type and value=number
type=type and value=string
```

Or for just the values in the []:

```
var str = "this is a test [type:number] further test [type:string]";
var reg = /\[([a-z:]+)\]/g;
while (match = reg.exec(str)) {
   console.log("type: " + match[1]);
}
```

Will log:

```
type: type:number
type: type:string
```

I also made your RegEx a little more specific. So you don't run into incorrect results once you get into parsing real text.